# excel copy conditional formatting relative cell

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting

[i have this table in excel, created new rule in conditional formatting where it will highlight or color the entire row of the selected cell depending on its status (pending, ship or delivered) by the way i used dropdownlist](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Kocao.jpg)

[conditional formatting rule](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OwnuD.jpg)

this rule is only applicable in cell R2C6, what I want to happen is to copy the conditional formatting to its relative cell, and apply the same rule if the STATUS is pending, ship or delivered. How can I apply the same rule in the following list without manually editing the cell reference in the conditional formatting rule?

Comment: You may use `format painter` method.

Comment: You can use VBA?

Comment: R2C6 should refer just to cell F2 because it's an absolute reference (therefore it's $F$2 to be precise). You probably have to change it to R[0]C6 or RC6 or something like that (that would translate into $F2). Check [this](https://excelchamps.com/formulas/r1c1/#How_R1C1_Reference_Style_Works) out. Is this level of change acceptable?

Comment: @Vetuka i dont know how to use VBA, maybe you teach me